# Durante um foreach quando incrementa a string duplica um caractere no final

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma api para uso pessoal e gerenciamento de mysqli que faz com que o usuário não precise de muitos códigos e nem do phpMyAdmin (para uso de site etc). Porém estou tentando combinar o comando INSERT INTO com uma função:

```
function Query($sqlcommand){
    return $this->mysqli_conexao($sqlcommand);
}

function InsertInto($table, $fields, $values){
    $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO $table ";

    $sqlCommand .= "("

    $resultField;

    foreach($fields as $field){
        $resultField .= "'" . $field . "',";
    }

    $sqlCommand .= ") VALUES (";

    $resultValue;
    foreach($values as $value){
        $resultValue = "'" . $value . "',";
    }

    $sqlCommand .= ")";

    echo $sqlCommand;
}
```

Porém no final sempre adiciona uma aspa e uma virgula a mais e causa erro.

Ex fica assim: `$miConnector->InsertInto('test', array('a','b'), array('letra a', 'letra b'));`

```
INSERT INTO `test` ('a','b',') VALUES ('letra a', 'letra b',')
```

Código completo: [MiConnectorAPI](https://github.com/nathan130200/MiConnector/)

> **Resolvi desta maneira sem o foreach e não deu erro:**

```
$sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (`" . join($fields, '`,`') . "`) VALUES ('" . join($values, '\',\'') . "')";
```

Comment: Descobri! Usei isso http://pastebin.com/StHpU1Gc

Comment: Você também poderia usar o `implode`, ficou um pouca coisa mais limpo que o teu: http://ideone.com/Zq1k0S

Comment: Sim mas esse código não vai ficar a amosta :) é só uma api/bridge do mysqli que estou desenvolvendo, mais valeu pela dica

Comment: @zekk revendo o implode realmente o seu código ficou bem limpo e vou utilizar em outra api.